# Intersecting buffer with county polygon to find county population that lies outside buffer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, intersection, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have previously created single ring buffers around points, and intersected theses with census tracts and summarized in order to calculate the population within the buffer. I now hope to intersect these buffers (that have the populations inside the buffer attached to the table) with a projected county shapefile in order to subtract the population within the buffer and county from the total county population.

My plan is to use intersect.
Is there a way to just keep the part of the buffer of which its center is located within a county?

I do not want the pieces that happen to extend into another county.

Will I have any issues with regard to overlaps with other buffers, and how should I deal with this?

Attached is a sample photo of the map using a smaller and more distinct buffer.

[image]

Comment: Explore using the Union tool instead. Then it would a subsequent filtering of data based upon ID's.

Comment: Okay. This seems like a good idea. The buffers have the store location and a subregion (county) it is located in. However the buffers are incredibly overlapped in populated areas. Once creating the unions, do you happen to have a suggestion for filtering and combining the buffer pieces together, but ignoring the pieces that are outside that subregion/county that the store is contained in?

Comment: That depends entirely on your id fields in your dataset and you'll be able to build selection queries on those and dissolve/delete/merge on that.

Comment: I have the idea of bringing either a union or intersection to stata, keeping only rows in which the county matches the store's county (two different variables at this point), and then coming back and summing by Original Buffer ID. Which method seems most accurate for what I want?